# NFA -> DFA powerset construction worst case

Tags: finite-automata

I am wondering what generic example there is so that an NFA with n states results into a DFA with $2^n$ states after the conversion by the subset construction. I know there is the example by Hopcroft et al. where the resulting DFA has $2^{n-1}$ states but I am looking for a result with exactly 2^n states.

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is not the same question as [An NFA with no equivalent DFA with fewer than $2^n$ states: Example and Proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54840/an-nfa-with-no-equivalent-dfa-with-fewer-than-2n-states-example-and-proof) since there $2^{n-1}$ states suffices but I am looking for $2^n$ states.

Comment: The question is answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16287) by J.-E. Pin.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't re-post your question multiple times: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139174/755